# Zabbix triggers, send mails to specific email IDs, which are not a user in Zabbix

Tags: centos6, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I recently started with Zabbix for monitoring around 150 VMs. These VMs are used for development purpose only and have been assigned to specific owners.  The owners **do not have a user in Zabbix**, as it is not required. Is it possible to **send mails to these specific owners**, when a trigger to the respective server occurs?

Its a Zabbix-2.2.4 server setup, on a CentOS 6.5. All components of zabbix are in the same server. At present I have configured using SendEmail to send mail via a remote SMTP server to email ID of the users created in Zabbix.

I guess there is no direct option, please help me with some ideas to implement it, if anyhow possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create user accounts for all the receivers, add corresponding media entries (emails) to them. Configure actions as usual, but place all of these users in a common usergroup that has "Frontend access" set to "Disabled" - this way they will be able to receive notifications, but not log into the frontend.

Alternatively, have a single user account with multiple user media entries for all the email addresses.

Comment: Thanks Richlv , I have put that as the last option. Just wanted to know if any other way it could be done.